# Clear the environment of the evalutor

Tags: python

Can I clear python environment, such that to bring the evaluator at the same state machine as after startup ?

I wish I would not restart the evalutor.

Comment: It might be possible, but it would be quite tricky. It would help if you explained the reason you need to do this, because there may be a simpler option.

Comment: I solve some problems of statistics, using pylab. After I pass from 1 problem to the next, I want to remove the environment.

Comment: Well, if you reset the entire environment, your code would no longer exist in memory, so how would you expect that to work? Or are you running separate scripts for each "problem"?

Comment: I forgot to add that I work interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't truly reset the state of the Python interpreter just with Python code, although you could do it with a custom C program which embeds the Python interpreter.

However, for your particular case, it would probably suffice to run each of your "problems" in a sub-interpreter, with something like this...

```
import sys
import code

def reset():
    raise SystemExit(123)

sys.modules['__builtin__'].reset = reset

banner = None

while 1:
    try:
        code.interact(banner=banner, local={})
        break
    except SystemExit as e:
        if e.code == 123:
            banner = 'Resetting...'
            continue
        raise
```

...then when you run that script, you can use it like this...

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01)
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> dir()
['__builtins__']
>>> a = 1
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', 'a']
>>> reset()
Resetting...
>>> dir()
['__builtins__']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>>globals().clear()
```

Comment: That won't reset `sys.modules`.

Comment: Also, `globals().clear()` will clear all the builtins, so you won't actually be able to run any code after doing it.